# Getting [object Object] by passing php string to onclick function using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to alert hello instead I'm getting [object Object].
Getting [object Object] by passing php string to onclick function using jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>

<a class="readmore" onclick="myFunction('<?php echo "hello";?>')">Readmore....</a>

<?php
call();
function call(){
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".readmore").click(function(link){
    alert(link);
  });
}); 
</script>
<?php }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `console.log(link)` - alert will always convert to string, which will always show "object" for an object

Comment: Note that jquery click event handler has no relation to the `onclick` attribute.  jquery click will always pass an event object (`link` in your code should be `eventObject`) - https://api.jquery.com/click/ which is why you get `[Object]` - because it's an event object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is your JavaScript code. You are calling a function, which does not exist. That's why it doesn't do anything. If you want to do it in jQuery you will have to define link. Otherwise, link is equal to [object Object], because link is passed by a function, which is called without the attribute link.

Fixed:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <a class="readmore" onclick="show_alert('<?php echo "hello";?>')">Readmore....</a>
    
    <?php
    call();
    function call(){
    ?>
    <script>
    function show_alert(link) {
      alert(link);
    }
    </script>
    <?php }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

With Jquery:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <a class="readmore" link="test">Readmore....</a>
    
    <?php
    call();
    function call(){
    ?>
    <script>
      $(".readmore").click(function(){
      link = $(".readmore").attr("link");
       alert(link);
      });
    </script>
    <?php }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry I want to use in jquery 
not a simple javascript

Comment: Okay, please look at the code. It is now done with Jquery and is based on the attribute link, instead of a OnClick function, which is not defined. Thats why it created the object[object error]